# Plotnine theme element_blank() doesn't seem to work - perhaps I'm not importing the package correctly?

Tags: python, plotnine

I've created a state map and would like to remove the x-axis and y-axis as these don't provided any value for this plot.

```
map_population_by_county = (
ggplot(map_population_by_county_data)
+ geom_map(aes(fill='Population2018'))
+ geom_label(aes(x = 'Longitude', y = 'Latitude', label='Population2018', size=2))
)
map_population_by_county
```

[image]

I expect that adding `+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())` should remove the axis and that I should similarly be able to modify more such as

```
+ theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

But when I add `+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())` I receive an error

```
map_population_by_county = (
ggplot(map_population_by_county_data)
+ geom_map(aes(fill='Population2018'))
+ geom_label(aes(x = 'Longitude', y = 'Latitude', label='Population2018', size=2))
+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
)
map_population_by_county

  File "<ipython-input-23-45e23f30fc6a>", line 5
    + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
            ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Adding a double equals "==" doesn't seem right but I tried it and received a new error, `NameError: name 'axis' is not defined`

Is it possible that I am not importing the plotnine package correctly?
In order for geom_point, etc. to work I had to import these specifically as `from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_map, geom_text, geom_label` in the jupyter notebook that I'm using.  Using `import plotnine as p9` or `from plotnine import *` would not even work for the map above.  I've tried adding `from plotnine import theme`, but that didn't work.

Comment: try `axis_text_x`. You're using the `r` syntax where you can separate variable names with `.`, but they changed the parameter names in `python` to be separated with `_`.

Comment: Thanks @cookesd !  When I used `from plotnine import *` and changed the `.` to the `_` then it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @cookesd - replacing `axis.text.x` (the R ggplot formulation) with `axis_text_x` for python plotnine resolved this issue.

In python the parameter names need to be separated with a `_`